# Is Euclid's algorithm for the GCD of two numbers wrong?

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

So today in Computer Science I was asked to write a program that used Euclid's algorithm to find the GCD of two numbers that you input. My teacher told us that if x is some positive integer larger than y, Euclid's algorithm was the GCD of x & y  =  the GCD of y & the remainder of x/y, (setting y = the remainder of x/y every time) while the remainder of x/y does not equal 0 (the final remainder not equaling zero being the answer).

My program is right... most of the time. When I input the numbers 50 & 23, or 98 and 59, it tells me their GCD is 2, which is obviously wrong because 23 & 59 are prime. Do you guys know if this formula is right?

Comment: The formula is definitely right. Perhaps one of the programming SEs can help you debug your code.

Comment: Yes, it is correct, you should post your code in the Programming exchange sites (or even tell us how you programmed the algorithm).

Comment: yall are much more kind than me.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I found the larger of the two numbers. Then I set the smaller variable equal to the remainder of the larger variable over the smaller variable, then I checked to see if the smaller variable then equaled zero (because the remainder was zero). If it did not, I set a third variable equal to the smaller variable. I would repeat this until the smaller variable did equal zero, then I would output the third variable.

Comment: @LarryK show me your code I can fix it

Comment: @alkabary Here's a dropbox link to my code (it's in C++):

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzgbfwao1zha29m/main.cpp?dl=0

 I couldn't fit the whole thing into a 500 character comment.

Comment: If you give the string of remainders for one of the wrong computations, one may be able to make a guess about the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euclid's algorithm is right and your program is wrong.

\begin{align}
50 - 23 & = 27 \\
27 - 23 & = 4 \\  \\
23 - 4 & = 19 \\  \\
19 - 4 & = 15 \\
15 - 4 & = 11 \\
11 - 4 & = 7 \\
7 - 4 & = 3 \\  \\
4 - 3 & = 1 \\
3 - 1 & = 2 \\
2 - 1 & = 1
\end{align}
Now you're looking for $\gcd(1,1)$, and that is $1$.
\begin{align}
98 - 59 & = 39 \\  \\
59 - 39 & = 20 \\  \\
39 - 20 & = 19 \\  \\
20 - 19 & = 1 
\end{align}
etc.

Comment: Where did the 19, 15, and 11 come from?

Comment: @LarryK : From subtracting. The point is that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$.  If $a>b$, then replace the pair $(a,b)$ with $(a-b,b)$, and the gcd is still the same. That's the idea of Euclid's algorithm. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Oh, I'm using division, and finding the remainder from that.

Comment: @LarryK it's the same, in principle, if $a>b$ then $a=qb+r$ with $b>r$, so $gcd(a,b)=gcd(qb+r,b)=gcd(qb+r-b,b)=...=gcd(r,b)=gcd(b,r)$. Remember that division is just substracting many times.

Comment: @LarryK : The reason for stating it in the form $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b)$ is that it's easy to prove those two are equal.  After that it can be seen that $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(r,b)$ where $r$ is the remainder on division of $a$ by $b$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: 50/23 remainder 4, 50/4 remainder 2, 50/2 remainder 0. This is essentially what my program does, and not one of those remainders equals one.

Comment: @LarryK : That's not how Euclid's algorithm works.  Divide $50$ by $23$; the remainder is $4$.  Then divide $23$ by $4$; the remainder is $3$.  Then divide $4$ by $3$; the remainder is $1$.  Then divide $3$ by $1$; the remainder is $0$.  If you were to take it a step further, you would divide $1$ by $0$ and the remainer would be $1$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm marking your answer as correct because of that comment.